# Can't access the assembly that installed into the GAC

Tags: asp.net, gac

I am sorry if this is stupid questions, but i've spend two days on this, and can't get it to work. 
Here's what I did:

1. Create a new class library project
2. Added a simple method `sayHi()` that returns a string
3. In the project properties checked "sign the assembly" and used a strong name key file
4. Compiled the application and copied the DLL to c:\windows\assemblies (and i also tried using the gacutil tool with similar results)
5. Added the following to machine.config   `<compilation><assemblies><add assembly="gacTestClass, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31418215e131202e" />`. This works just fine, because if i misspell the assembly name, any .net app will fail and complain about that line.
6. Using the assembly cache viewer in the .NET framework configuration tool i can see the assembly in the cache.
7. Now, when i try to use that, my app fails when i do either `using gacTestClass` or `gacTestClass.gacTest.sayHi()`. I get an error saying that the type or namespace could not be found.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Ok, i followed a suggestion and I will try to make this work with web.config, rather than machine.config.

I added the following to my web.config `<compilation><assemblies><add assembly="gacTestClass, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31418215e131202e" />` and made sure that it works by misspelling the name, and watching the app fail. 
Now, when I try to add `using gacTestClass` to the top of my .cs file, i get an error saying that the type or namespace could not be found.

Just in case, here's the code the for the gacTestClass

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
[assmbly:AssemblyKeyFile("sayHi.snk")]
namespace gacTestClass {
    public class gacTest {
        public string sayHi() {
            return "Hello there!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think even if the assembly is in GAC you will have to add a reference. The advantage is that the assembly need not be copied to any folder.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the particular error message you are getting? If you adding the assembly to machine.config or the web.config you should NOT need to add a reference within your application.

Comment: @sestocker: If his app isn't ASP.Net, he will.

Comment: @SLaks if its not a web app, he can use an app.config. I do this all the time for Sharepoint. You only need to add the GAC-ed assembly into the config.

Comment: When i try to add it using the "using gacTestClass;" i get "The type or namespace name 'gacTestClass' could not be found"

Comment: What does your calling code look like? Everything looks good from what I can tell - it has to be something none of us can think of at the moment.

Comment: Are you getting the error at runtime? I would think that Visual Studio would be complaining on the using statement right away.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Namespace" publicKeyToken="token" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding></runtime>
```

Move the compilation section from the machine.config to your web.config and give it a try. It should work fine in the machine.config but I assume that if you are GAC-ing an assembly, many applications will be using it. You will want each application to be able to choose which version of the DLL they are going to use (for easier upgrade paths).

Also, seems obvious, but make sure the method (gacTestClass.gacTest.sayHi()) you are trying to access is public.

Comment: I tried moving the code to web.config, but it didn't work. Yes, the assembly is GACed, and the class and the method are both public.

Comment: That's what i thought. I am still stuck though. It seems like such a simple problem

Comment: Nope, adding the <runtime>... didn't help either. 
I don't understand, why is this so hard? I've read a dozen articles on how to do this, and every single one says the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: Try right-clicking on your project, clicking Add Reference, and adding your DLL file.

In general, you should never modify `machine.config`.

Comment: Why not? I have multiple apps, and I don't want to have to add a reference every time a new app is installed on the server.

Comment: Because if, next year, you get a new server, or if you move to .Net 4, you'll probably forgot to re-modify `machine.config`.

Comment: Also, so that multiple applications from different people can live on the same server.  **Don't use global state to solve a local problem.**  http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx  http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/15/9907370.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realized that machine.config modifications are a bad thing, but it makes perfect sense. I tried adding this to web.config, but it still doesn't work.